# "Ssp update received" toast keep showing from time to time

Tags: custom-roms, internet, toast-notifications

Sometimes I get a toast (a temporary popup on the screen) saying something like:

> Ssp update received for package XXX

where XXX is the package of the app i'm currently running. It might not be exactly this text as it's hard to read the whole message (disappears after a short time).

It seems it is shown when an app is accessing the Internet. It also seems it started occuring when I've installed "Onavo" app, but it kept occurring even after I've uninstalled it.

my phone is rooted and has some tweaks. it's Samsung Galaxy S3 with Omega ROM 50.1 , which is based on stock samsung ROM (Android 4.1.2).

It also has the Xposed framework.

Does anybody know the reason for this message, and how to avoid getting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the API demos, as I've searched google for this text, and found this:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master%5E1%5E1..master%5E1/

looking at the file it says, its name is "AppUpdateSspReceiver.java" .

It makes sense that very few know about this problem, as this app is mainly used for developers who wish to see what's new on the new version of Android, and how to use the new stuff.

I have no idea what is its purpose and what it tries to demonstrate - the comment there says "Executed when a new version of the application is is installed.", but it doesn't seem the case).

Anyway, uninstalling the API demos seems to solve the problem.

Can anyone please tell me what is this demo?